# Put redux actions in a typescript class in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I have some redux actions in a class like below example:

```
export class MyAction { 

  export const updateUserInfo = (uid: string, info: Profile) => {
   return {
            type: UserActionType.UPDATE_USER_INFO,
            payload: { uid, info }
          }
    }

  export const userInfo = (info: Profile) => {
    return {
             type: UserActionType.USER_INFO,
             info
           }
    }

 export const clearAllData = () => {
    return {
             type: UserActionType.CLEAR_ALL_DATA_USER
           }
    }
}
```

To use this action class in the component I need to create an object the time I need to use in `mapDispatchToProps()` function like this:

```
export class HomeHeader extends React.Component {

  _myAction: MyAction;  

  constructor(){
      this._myAction = new MyAction();
   }

}

// - Map dispatch to props
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    logout: () => dispatch(this._myAction.clearAllData()) // !!!!!
  }
}

export default connect(null,mapDispatchToProps)
```

The problem is that I can't have access to `_myAction` as it's defined in the component class and object will be created in the constructor. Of course there some ways but anti pattern which is not my case.
How can I put my actions in a class and use it for component not to be anti pattern.

Comment: Just avoid the class, and keep pure functions. It makes not sense what you are doing.

Comment: @Hosar I'm writing in typescript so it could make sense if I follow some patterns to have cleaner code. Following this pattern I will have cohesion in code not to mess all functions up.

Comment: Using a class like that doesn't give you cleaner code. Typescript is not about classes, it's about types. You don't need to use classes to get benefits from Typescript. I recommend this library https://github.com/aikoven/typescript-fsa that combines power of typescript with redux